# 400 Bad Request error when placing an order on Binance

Tags: trading, binance

I am having trouble placing a sell order on Binance. I am using the Binance API to make the call, and I always get a 400 Bad Request error.

The call I am making is the following:

```
https://fapi.binance.com/fapi/v1/order
X-MBX-APIKEY: <API key>
X-MBX-TIMESTAMP: <timestamp>
X-MBX-SIGNATURE: <signature>
```

content:

```
symbol=BTCUSDT
side=Sell
type=LIMIT
timeInForce=GTC
quantity=0.002
price=29978.30
leverage=20
```

There is enough balance in the account to make the trade.

Can anyone help me identify the problem?

Comment: Bad request error means that the API backend doesn't recognize the given information in your request.  How are you composing your request and how are you sending in the information?  Please include your code.

Comment: Also, if you can check the response body, a lot of the time it will tell you exactly what you got wrong

Answer (score 0):

The error message returned from server will be very helpful for debug.